# jsPlumb make an element droppable

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I'm creating a logic gate drawing tool where users can add in gates and inputs and drag them around which are connected via jsPlumb.

What I want is a div styled like a trash can that when the user drops a logic gate or input on it, the element is deleted.

I've tried to mirror jQuery's droppable but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
jsPlumbInst.droppable('trashcan', {
    scope: 'logic-element',
    drop: function(e, ui){
         deleteElement();
    }
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging it's best to use jQuery's draggable and droppable and in the draggable options add:

```
$el.draggable({
    drag: function(){
        jsPlumbInst.repaintAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is $el ? specific element?